# App not loading: "localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docker-compose

I just spent a week upgrading rails to 4.2.10, and upgraded a whole bunch of gems and such, and now that I've finally convinced rails to run without errors, my app won't actually load.

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I have no idea where to even start trying to debug this.

The development.log file doesn't have any errors. The entire file says:

```
^[[1m^[[36mAppConfiguration Load (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  `configurations`.* FROM `configurations` WHERE `configurations`.`type` IN ('AppConfiguration') AND `configurations`.`name` = 'Default configuration' LIMIT 1^[[0m
Cache read: Spree::Config
Dalli::Server#connect memcached:11211
Cache fetch_hit: Spree::Config
Cache read: Spree::Config
Cache fetch_hit: Spree::Config
Cache read: Spree::Config
Cache fetch_hit: Spree::Config
```

And nothing new is printed when I hit the page.

`docker-compose logs -f abc` just says:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.10 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2018-08-17 14:48:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-08-17 14:48:01] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2018-08-17 14:48:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18 port=3000
```

Would my Gemfile be useful? What else would helpful to share?

It's not a local browser issue, because `curl` responds with `(52) Empty reply from server`, as well.

In Firefox: `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

ETA: Solved by adding `-b 0.0.0.0` at the end of `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: I am having the exact same problem and setting `-b 0.0.0.0` worked for me too...did you ever find anything else?